# Compile a Flex CSS file into a SWF using the command line

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex4, flex3

I understand that in Flex builder we can right click on a CSS file and choose 'compile to swf' and our CSS SWFs will automatically be compiled along with the main app.

Is possible to compile the CSS file only (not with the main app) from the command line?

I want to :

- Give clients a Flex CSS file to hand edit
- Allow them to upload the file via a CMS
- Trigger a server process to run the compiler from the command line, outputting the compiled SWF to the appropriate server path.

This would of course be a whole lot simpler if Flex properly supported text-based CSS files (without requiring manually applying styles using AS3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and really easy just type:

```
mxmlc yourFIle.css
```

at the command prompt